# Can't release unused CALayer memory when using multiple layers

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, uiimage, calayer, instruments

I am using multiple CALayer's in my application with large UIImage as contents. 
unfortunately, when I don't need the layer nor the image - the memory is not freed.

the code I use to create the layer is:

```
UIImage *im = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_1.jpg"];
CALayer * l = [CALayer layer];
[l setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
[l setPosition:CGPointMake(512, 384)];
[l setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];
[l setHidden:NO];
[l setContents:(id) im.CGImage];
[self.layer addSublayer:l]; // self is a subclass of UIView
[self.tmpArr addObject:l]; // self.tmpArr contains the layers I am using (one in this example)
```

the code I use to release the layer and it's contents is :

```
CALayer * l = [self.tmpArr objectAtIndex:i];
[l removeFromSuperlayer];
[l setHidden:YES];
[l setContents:nil];
[self.tmpArr removeAllObjects];
```

when I'm using the instruments memory profiler I see the real memory increasing when creating the layer but never decreasing when freeing there. 
I can't use release since I am using ARC. what do I do wrong here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UIImage's `imageNamed:` method uses a static cache that is only released upon tight memory situations.

Your options are:

1. Use `-[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` instead.
2. Ignore the problem. The cache is cleaned up when a memory notification comes in.

Comment: Thanks! the first option made significant improvement to my app.

Comment: Hi all, It strikes me that you guys have a better understanding of CALayer that me. I have a CALayer malloc issue posted, if any of you could take a look I'd be very grateful...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715727/setneedsdisplay-drawrect-or-calayer-causing-dispatch-continuation-alloc-from-he

Answer (score 0):

Just for documenting another answer. The image that I created in my code was drawn at runtime using `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`. The produced object is CGImageRef. I simply forgot to release it using `CGImageRelease` causing the memory consumption to increase gradually and after 3 or 4 animation, the application crashes due to memory constraint.

Always release an `CGImageRef`.