# CALayer seems to retain its contents - how to release resources?

Tags: ios, memory-management, core-animation, calayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t release unused CALayer memory when using multiple layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494980/cant-release-unused-calayer-memory-when-using-multiple-layers)

I have an app which allows the user to browse a series of images that are CALayers. I found that after I added more than 20 to the screen the iPad 2 would crash - obviously I need to dynamically load them in when visible on the screen.

So I implemented this, by removing the CALayer from its SuperLayer when no longer needed. What I found however is that the memory does not disappear when viewed in the 'Activity Monitor". It does however get freed when I 'simulate a memory warning' in the simulator. Fine you might think - that's what memory warnings are for. *However* - I still find the iPad runs out of RAM as I browse the images, the memory usages goes up and up until it crashes. Does anyone know a way to force a CALayer to release its resources?

Here's my code, **note if I omit assigning the layer contents** then the memory usage remains low (but of course you don't see the image)

```
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];

    frontLayer = [CALayer layer];
    frontLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 952, 650);
    frontLayer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;
```

Note I am **not using ARC**, and after I remove the layer from its superlayer I release it (it is retained by a property). The fact that the memory seems to get reclaimed with a low memory warning makes me think it's not a problem with the way I am retaining/releasing but I am open to ideas.

Comment: Can you not just set the layer's contents to nil prior to removing it from it's super layer?

Comment: @zneak - No, not using ARC, sorry should have made that clear. I have updated the question.

Comment: @jmstone This does not have any effect. I have also tried using CFRelase() on the contents, however this causes a crash in itself (over releasing I'm guessing)

Comment: Hi all, It strikes me that you guys have a better understanding of CALayer that me. I have a CALayer malloc issue posted, if any of you could take a look I'd be very grateful...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715727/setneedsdisplay-drawrect-or-calayer-causing-dispatch-continuation-alloc-from-he

Answer (score 1):

I discovered this is actually a duplicate of this post

[UIImage imageNamed:@""]; uses caching, when I use [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@""] the problem goes away.

[Can't release unused CALayer memory when using multiple layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494980/cant-release-unused-calayer-memory-when-using-multiple-layers)