# Image memory not being freed

Tags: ios, ipad, memory-management, core-animation, calayer

I have an issue on an iPad app where every images (all 1024x768) displayed takes 3Mo on RAM without freeing them when not needed, leading to a crash after some time.

I load images using "contentsOfFile" method which should (in my understanding) release memory when the memory is low and the app doesn't need it anymore but it just doesn't seem to be the case (even when i simulate a memory warning on simulator).

I made a really simple test class to illustrate the problem below (swift 1.2).

When the application loads it creates a view, add sublayers filled with the images, and then when I tap on the screen I expect the 72Mo taken by the uncompressed bitmaps data (used by Core Animation to render the layer) to be freed (or at least to be freed when i simulate a memory warning), which it never does.

(Note : I use ARC on both my main project and this test project)

```
ViewController: UIViewController {

  func tap(gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer)
  {
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
      var tmpV = self.view.viewWithTag(1000)
      // tried everything to release memory
      for subLayer : CALayer in tmpV?.layer.sublayers as! [CALayer!] {
        subLayer.contents = nil
      }
      tmpV?.layer.sublayers.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
      tmpV?.removeFromSuperview()
      tmpV = nil
    }
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //add gesture to remove images from view
    var gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tap:"))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

    //loading images
    var imagesArray : [UIImage!]! = self.fillImagesArray()

    //adding those images to a view
    let tmpV = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 768))
    for img in imagesArray {
      var layer = CALayer()
      layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 768)
      layer.contents = img.CGImage
      tmpV.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
    tmpV.tag = 1000
    self.view.addSubview(tmpV)    
  }

  func fillImagesArray() -> [UIImage!]{
    var array : [UIImage!] = []
    for i in 0 ... 23 {
      var image : UIImage?
      var filename = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("image \(i)", ofType: "png")
      image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filename!)      
      array.append(image)
    }
    return array
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }
}
```

EDIT:

To add a few more details, here is a screenshot taken from Profile/Allocations tool, so as I said I guess that the memory is taken by CA when rendering the layers.

[image: Memory screenshot]
When the images aren't displayed on screen, the memory is still really low, but once they got displayed they aren't released even after removal.

I tried to draw the tmpV layer, remove the sublayers and then adding the drawn image to tmpV.layer.contents in `viewDidAppear`, and if I do so my image is correct and the memory stays low but it cost around 1.5 seconds to draw the layer (I need my app to be fast and I can't afford this time).

The only way I found to release the memory was to add the images into a class variable array, and emptied it on `tap` func. But I'd need to reload the images again if I want to re-create an image and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: What makes you think: "load images using "contentOfFile" method which should (in my understanding) release memory when the memory is low and the app doesn't need"?

Comment: Just a guess coming from reading answers on different SO posts like those :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494980/cant-release-unused-calayer-memory-when-using-multiple-layers
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588338/ios-uiimage-storage-formats-memory-usage-and-encoding-decoding

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> I load images using "contentOfFile" method which should (in my
>   understanding) release memory when the memory is low and the app
>   doesn't need it anymore...

(should be content**s**OfFile, with an "s")

That's not quite correct. The other common way of loading images, imageNamed, caches the images it loads in case you need them again.

The contentsOfFile method for loading images does not do any caching. It hands you back an image, and then you need to maintain a strong reference to the image or it will be deallocated. You need to track all strong references to the image and make sure they are all nilled out once you are done with them.

Let's walk through the code you posted and the ownership of the images (and the CGImage data from those images.)

You store your images in an array that's defined in the scope of your fillImagesArray method. That method returns the array, so the caller will take ownership of the array. You're storing the array of images in another local variable, imagesArray, in the scope of viewDidAppear. That array should be released when viewDidAppear returns.

You install the CGImage data from the images into a set of layers which you install as sublayers of a view, tmpV, that you create.

The original UIImage objects should be released and deallocated when viewDidAppear returns. However, the image data is now stored in a bunch of layers.

You then install tmpV as a subview of your view controller's content view.

So when all that is done the image data is owned by your layers. The layers are owned by your view's layer, which is owned by your view, tmpV. That view is owned by your view controller's content view. I don't see any other ownership of the image data. The chain of strong references has a single point, the fact that your tmpV view was added as a subview of your view controller's content view.

So, you should be able to get rid of the whole kit and caboodle simply by removing tmpV from it's superview. If that works, the data should be deallocated.

The other work you do of zeroing out the image data from the layers, and removing the layers, should not be needed. In fact, it might cause problems. I would remove all that code. In particular, the call that empties out the array of sublayers looks like a bad idea to me. If you're going to iterate through the array of layers, I would suggest you call removeFromSuperlayer on each one (although you'd need to copy the array of layers before enumerating it so it doesn't mutate while it's being enumerated.)

You should log the code that fetches your tmpV view via tag to make sure it finds the view.

How are you concluding that your memory is not being freed?, and where are you measuring it?

Comment: Thank you for analyzing the code. I am sure that the tmpV view is fetched because when I tap on the screen all the images are removed from it. I agree that zeroing out the layer.contents etc seems weird but it was just a try since nothing seems to work. I measure the memory with the panel in XCode which shows memory/disk/network usage + CPU. I also used "Profile" + "Allocations" and this gives me the same result. I'll update the question with a screenshot and maybe more details. (btw I fixed the contentsOfFile typo, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

The programmer is responsible for all memory usage associated with `contentsOfFile`. If you have a strong reference to an image object, say in an array, it will not be removed from memory until you remove it from the array and there are no strong references to it.

You might want to consider using `NSCache` and it's associated `NSDiscardableContent` Protocol to control the images.

Comment: Since in that case the array is a local variable, shouldn't it be freed at the end of `viewDidAppear` function ? If so then the only strong reference I see should be in the differents CALayer that I remove later.
I never used NSCache before so I'm unsure about how to use it, I gave it a try but I didn't really get how it could help freeing the memory.
Note : I updated my question to add some more details.

Comment: All the images are added to the view: `self.view.addSubview(tmpV)` so the view has a strong reference to them. As long as the view exists the added images will be strongly retained.